# How should I apply a terraform root module construct using terragrunt?

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

I'm working on a terragrunt code base for the first time, having used terraform a lot in the past without terragrunt. I'm a bit confused as to the structure terragrunt seems to enforce. I would usually organise my terraform thus:

```
main.tf
--> module
    main.tf
--> module2
    main.tf
```

This is listed as best practice on the terraform docs:

> ### The Root Module
>
> Terraform always runs in the context of a single root module. A
> complete Terraform configuration consists of a root module and the
> tree of child modules (which includes the modules called by the root
> module, any modules called by those modules, etc.).

[Source](https://www.terraform.io/language/files#the-root-module)

But none of the terragrunt structures seem to represent this. It seems to be designed so that each module is independent and run using the `run-all` command.

This seems problematic to me, from the existing code base I can see that this initialises terraform for every module and I'd say causes issues with sharing secrets between modules. So I'd prefer to work with one root module and multiple child modules.

I can't find a terragrunt pattern that will allow me to do this?

I'm also confused as to how this responsibility is decomposed, do I actually structure my terraform (as above) or do I need an extra root `.hcl` file?

I'm after something a [**little** like this I guess](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/keep-your-terraform-code-dry/#dry-common-terraform-code-with-terragrunt-generate-blocks)

```
└── live
    ├── prod
    │   ├── terragrunt.hcl
    │   ├── app
    │   │   └── terragrunt.hcl
    │   ├── mysql
    │   │   └── terragrunt.hcl
    │   └── vpc
    │       └── terragrunt.hcl
    ├── qa
    │   ├── terragrunt.hcl
    │   ├── app
    │   │   └── terragrunt.hcl
    │   ├── mysql
    │   │   └── terragrunt.hcl
    │   └── vpc
    │       └── terragrunt.hcl
    └── stage
        ├── terragrunt.hcl
        ├── app
        │   └── terragrunt.hcl
        ├── mysql
        │   └── terragrunt.hcl
        └── vpc
            └── terragrunt.hcl
```

But this example just talks about specifying the `provider` block and nothing about a root `main.tf`. So I'm lost?

Comment: It might be the case that you are looking for a structure like this? https://spacelift.io/blog/iac-architecture-patterns-terragrunt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each TF module you used to use consumed inputs, created resources and provided outputs. The wiring of the modules was done via `main.tf` you are referring to in plain Terraform.

In your case with Terragrunt now, the wiring will be done by `terragrunt.hcl` files. On the module level (e.g.`live/prod/app/terragrunt.hcl`) you could define the module dependencies, i.e. where are the input values for this modules input variables, e.g.:

```
inputs {
  username = dependency.iam.output.user.name
}
```

With this in mind, you might or might not use root-level `terragrunt.hcl` files. If you want to invoke the parent-folder `terragrunt.hcl` code, you need to add the following block into your module:

```
include "root" {
  path   = find_in_parent_folders()
  expose = true
}
```

See the docs for this function [here](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/reference/built-in-functions/#find_in_parent_folders).